# Connect to remote mysql DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB and Websever on seperate VMs, I want to display the contents on the db but i am getting 500 response.

I can connect from my webnode to db using;

```
mysql -u user -h 10.xx.xx.xx -p
```

but i cant connect from test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("10.xx.xx.xx:3306", "user", "password", "db");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

500 Internal Server Error

Can anyone help point out where im going wrong?

Comment: Yes, your server error log can. So go check.

Comment: Your server doesn't let external connection probably. Try to create firewall inbound rule to 3306 port with your ip. Or GRANT your user to access tables etc.

Comment: First you need to check your error log (assuming you're generating one) or turn on error reporting. A 500 error is a generic cover for any server side problem, designed not to accidentally give away any specific details which might harm security. To find out the underlying problem you need to log or report the real exception that PHP generated. As mert says there's a good chance it's a problem with remote connections being firewalled or just disallowed by mysql. But if you confirm the exact error we can be a lot more certain.

Comment: P.s. you can probably already read a lot of helpful stuff online about how to set up mysql and/or your hosting environment to allow the connection. Have you done any research already?

Answer (score -1):

The PHP statement you have written is right, but have you created user "user" with proper privileges ?

I got same error while connecting to database then I searched a lot and I found that I have not created user with proper privileges so  check for it.